# How to Set Conditional Formatting without Dragging Down?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I am trying to format my whole document using Conditional Formatting. If the result from the basis[sheet] is DO and LATE, data[sheet] will automatically set it blue. I can set it one by one to put a color but what if you got so many rows and columns? I am currently setting the formula one by one :(. My formula is =OR($C4="DO",$C4="LATE").

Here is the link to view the image:http://postimg.org/image/6qbic0crt/
and the link to download the file:http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/502381/SAMPLE.xlsx

Any help would be appreciated. Hopefully the question is clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just select all of your sheet and choose conditional formatting on the home ribbon
then new rule, then choose rules equals to Do. Then, run this as well to Late.

Comment: Pardon. I am not sure I got what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

In the picture you linked you are trying to format B4:C14 as blue, if the text in C column is either 'do' or 'late'

The formula you already posted will actually work perfectly well, you just need to highlight all of the data instead of 2 cells at a time.

i.e.

Highlight B4 to C14

Conditional Formatting

New Rule

Use a formula to determine which cells to format

Formula = the same one you've already used